# Is there a for loop or purrr solution to this?

Tags: r

I am trying to do some power calculations for a project. The code is working but my for loop is not. I had two questions

a) Can somebody tell me where i am going wrong and
b) Is there a purrr option to this

```
install.packages("WebPower")
library(WebPower)


rate <- function(cases,weeks,population){cases/weeks/population}
rate <- rate(cases = 243,weeks = 15,population = 153126)

wp.poisson(exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = 0.5,alpha = 0.05,power = 0.8,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson')

res_0.5 <- wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = 0.5,alpha = 
0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson')
res_0.4 <- wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = 0.4,alpha = 
0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson')
res_0.3 <- wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = 0.3,alpha = 
0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson')
res_0.2 <- wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = 0.2,alpha = 
0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson')}

for(i in seq(0.2,0.5,0.1)){
paste0('res_',i) <- wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = i,alpha = 
0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson')}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need a loop, loop over the `exp1` values.  It is better the store the output in a `list` though instead of creating multiple objects in the global env.

```
v1 <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2)
out <- lapply(v1, function(ex)

   wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = ex,
   alpha = 0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson'))

names(out) <- paste0('res_', v1)
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or with `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
out <- map(v1, ~ .x

   wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = .x,
   alpha = 0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson'))
```

and then change the name of the `list` before doing the `list2env`

---

In the `for` loop we need `assign`

```
for(i in seq(0.2,0.5,0.1)){
   assign(paste0('res_',i), wp.poisson(n = seq(80000, 200000, 10000), 
       exp0 = rate*2,exp1 = i,alpha = 
          0.05,alternative ='less',family = 'Poisson'))
  }
```